# Is there any way to avoid plugin cross incompatibility in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I am thinking about learning front-end framework vue.js on vscode instead of jetbeans webstorm (pretty much wanting to switch to vscode). And I usually use vscode for competetive programming with cpp and python.

So the problem is when I turn on my VSCode editor the preset (all the plugins, snippets etc.) are enabled for competetive programming.

Is there any kind of VSCode "profiles" where I would have different layouts for different programming languages/frameworks I want to work with without plugin cross incompatibility?

Comment: What is "plugin cross incompatibility"? Give it a definition please.

Comment: @LexLi Like when snippets does merge with other snippets, or like when my plugins turned on for cpp are available when I am working with js

Comment: If you actually mean incompatibilities among VSCode extensions, that's something unavoidable due to the extension model. Extension authors might not be able to test against too many scenarios, but you can reach out to most of them on GitHub.